# magento attribute add error

Tags: magento, attributes, prototype

Sorry my english very bad.

My problem:

magento add attribute button gives the error after. After pressing the Add button is happening passive

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this error

Comment: use old version of  prototype.js

Comment: Check if nay module you have is inserting any js on the admin page, happened to me couple of weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

Check if nay module you have is inserting any js on the admin page, happened to me couple of weeks ago.